# MySQL how to group into subgroups of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this DB: (*note `id` is unique*)

[image]

I am trying to get this:

[image]

What would be an efficient SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: You don't really want to do this type of operation in SQL.  It is much better to do at the application layer.  Possible, but really not worth it.

Comment: It's better to do this on app side (Java/php/...) Use a simple order by for `group_id`, then iterate through the resultset. If the `group_id` changes, apply the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    foo2.group_id AS group_id,
    if(foo1.group_id = foo2.group_id, foo1.id, NULL) AS id,
    if(foo1.group_id = foo2.group_id, foo1.some_attr, NULL) AS some_attr
 FROM mytable AS foo1
    JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM mytable) as foo2        
    ORDER BY group_id, id
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing a result set with formatting of the result set. SQL result sets are tables of consistent rows. The closest you can come is to change the sequence of your column names in the SELECT statement. You'll have to add your own line breaks at time of presentation.